# Location request with/out play services

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

At first I made a location request app without the play services package. The APK weighed 357kb. At first the location was OK but suddenly it started to be inaccurate and on a different device I got a lot of "service not available" error for the geocoder.

I started reading about it and got to the point where I changed everything to work with the play services mechanism. It's still giving me the inaccurate address (I wish I knew why) and I still didn't work with the other device to see if the "service not available" problem happens there but the APK now weighs 1.7mb! for the same exact thing!

Is there any benefit for using the play services mechanism for the location request?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the major benefit is that you dont have to manage all the different location providers it is done for you

Comment: You mean that 1 line of code where you tell it you want to use the GPS (in my case)? The address I got with/without the play services was inaccurate anyway :) it was ok at first, I don't know why it changed all of a sudden.

Comment: no I mean several lines of code where if one provider does not exist or gets disabled by the user. plus there are battery optimizations done too

Comment: So if I want to use only the GPS and if that's not there, I want to do nothing, play services gives me no other benefits?

Comment: did you read the documentation? http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html it tells you what it does

Comment: Ofcourse I did when I started changing my app but after actually doing it, it seems to save me a few lines of code that were already there and working so I was wondering if I was missing something. Maybe it is better for a more robust app that what I'm doing. Thanks.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @maszter Q: `Is there any benefit for using the play services mechanism` A: `The major benefit is that you dont have to manage all the different location providers` I directly answered his question so please tell me how this is not an answer